# Dot at end of numbers in CSV file

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-csv

I have an excel file with some numbers followed by a dot, say:

> 12345.

I created a simple macro to convert and save the excel file into a .csv file.

The problem is the CSV file does not save the dot. The data comes out as 12345 and not 12345. I also tried manually adding the dot and saving the csv file, but the dot just dissappears.

Anyway to add the dot into the CSV file?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoboK.jpg

Comment: Try enclosing the values in `""`.

Comment: As in, saving 12345"." in the csv file? No excel on current computer so can't test it now, although I'm pretty sure I tried doing that and it did'nt work out.

Comment: No, like this: `"12345."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a single quote/apostrophe in front of the number (without a closing quote at the end), so that it reads it as text and does not auto-format it as number.

For example you have:

```
    12345.
```

Excel will auto-format that column as a number and drop the period unless you specify that it's a text only column.

Change it to:

```
    '12345.
```

Excel will read that value as a text column and will not save the apostrophe in a text-based CSV file.

Edit:
In testing this, I found that ff you save it as "12345.", Excel changes the CSV file to """12345.""".

Comment: use a custom format, and format the number as **#.** - excel will then put a . on the end of each number